# Obtain the public key's hash from a X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I hold a `X509Certificate2` object, I can access the public key via the `PublicKey` property. For a different API I need to obtain the public key's SHA-1 hash. Is there a simple way to get it from the `PublicKey` property?

I tried the following:

```
var sha1 = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(signerCert.PublicKey.???)
```

But what to put instead of the "???". It doesn't look like there is some kind of "Raw" data property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be `signerCert.GetPublicKey()` instead of accessing the `PublicKey` property directly.